# How to download the CSV file in my website from other webserver?

Tags: .net, asp.net, csv, webserver

In my website I need to download a CSV file from other webserver through coding.

How can I do so?

Comment: Is the CSV file accessible from FTP or HTTP?

Comment: What have you tried already? And how do you access the file on the other website?

Comment: @Kangkan:I don't know how to access that the file that is on other website. I am new into these things. Can you give me some basic tutorial or refer me to an article where in I can get to know this.

Comment: Just let me know, if you need to take the file (not using coding) then how you do it? Do you reach a web page (like: http://www.othersite.com/getcsvfile.htm)) on the said website and download or can you do something like http://www.othersite.com/getcsvfile/mycsvfile.csv. This is called accessing the file over HTTP.

Comment: I am trying to use the second option that you gave. othersite.com/getcsvfile/mycsvfile.csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use HTTP to get the file the [System.Net.WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class is probably your best bet. You can probably do a quick Google search on this to find some tutorials.

For FTP see, [System.Net.FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)

Comment: [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is maybe more usefull.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll have to check that out.

Comment: You might want to specifically mention `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`, depending on the level of complexity that is required in creating the request.  If it's not that complex, then @kerrubin comment about `WebClient` is correct, in that it would be easier (I prefer `HttpWebRequest` myself).